# First printf() in series of printfs malfunctioning, returning unpredictable results

Tags: c, string, atoi

I've made a simple function that takes a string of digits and returns them in int form:

```
int     my_atoi(char *str)
{
   int i;
   int num;

   i = 0;
   if (str[0] == '-')
       i++;
   while (str[i] != '\0')
   {
       num = num * 10 + str[i] - '0';
       i++;
   }
   if (str[0] == '-')
       num = num * -1;
   return (num);
}
```

I came up with the following unit tests in my main:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *m_i = "-999";
    char *odd_neg = "-2147483648";

    printf("%d\n", my_atoi(m_i));
    printf("%d\n", my_atoi(odd_neg));
    return (0);
}
```

No matter how many different strings of digits I test it with (positive or negative), and no matter the string, my *first* printf - even if there is just one - will return an unpredictable number. For example, "-999" returned -2139331687. All subsequent printfs function normally.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-Wall` (or whatever flag your compiler uses to enable warnings), and the compiler should immediately tell you the problem -- the `num` local variable is uninitialized, so it might have any random value on calling the function.

You need to initialize it -- change the declaration to `int num = 0;`.

Comment: It's just so sad that the grossly trivial amount of debugging required to find this out was not done by OP:((

Comment: This did answer the question, thank you. I compile with the flags -Wall -Werror -Wextra using gcc and it did not display any Warnings. (though it is obvious). I'm sorry I made you sad @MartinJames.

Comment: One more note about the -Wall flag. If num were sent to a function as in: `num = function_call(num, variable);`, then the flag would have raised this.